# Does bed work after minecraft world corrupts

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My world got corrupted and I recovered it, but I can't find my house. Will I spawn at my bed even tho the world was corrupted?

Comment: Depends what was corrupted.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe. Maybe not.

The player's spawn point is saved in `level.dat` for singleplayer worlds, or `playerdata/[UUID].dat` for multiplayer, in the `SpawnX`, `SpawnY` and `SpawnZ` tags. If that file was corrupted and restored, it's possible that this data was destroyed. If they exist, *and* there's still a bed at these coordinates, which might not be the case due to the corruption, killing yourself will work.

If you want to find out, I suggest opening this file using an external tool, such as [NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac), and check for the tags.